# always the first row of the html table gets deleted using php code

Tags: php, mysql

> order.php

```
  require_once(conn.php);

session_start();
$itemId=$_SESSION['itemId'];
$tnumber=$_SESSION['tnumber'];
$custno=$_SESSION['custno'];

 $sql="select itemId,subtitle,price,quantity from cart where tnumber='$tnumber'" ;
 $res=mysqli_query($dbhandle,$sql);
 $total=0;
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href='cartbox.css'/>
</head>
<body>
    <h1></h1>
    <script src="home.js"></script>

        <div id="shopping-cart"> </div>


    <?php

                echo "<table id='t1' border='1'>
                <th>Subtitle</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                </tr>";   
          while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)) 
          {
          $amount=$row['price']*$row['quantity'];
          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td>" .$row['subtitle'] ."</td>";
          echo "<td>" .$row['quantity'] ."</td>";
          echo "<td>" .$row['price'] ."</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $amount . "</td>";
          echo' <form id="addform" method="post" action="cartdelete.php"> ';
         echo "<td><input type='submit' value='x' name='submit'></td>";

         echo "<td><input type='text' name='itemId'  value= ".$row['itemId']."></td>";     

         $total = $total+ $amount;

         }
         echo"</form>";
         echo "</table>";
         ?>
       <?php echo $total ?> 
      <input type="button" name="continue" value="Continue Order" style="position: absolute;top:200px;" onclick="location.href='customerdicecream.php'">

       </body>
       </html>
```

> cartdelete.php

```
      <?php
      require_once(conn.php);
      $itemId=(filter_input(\INPUT_POST,'itemId'));
      $sql1="select itemId from cart";
      $res1=mysqli_query($dbhandle,$sql1);
      $row=mysqli_fetch_array($res1);
      $itemId1=$row['itemId'];

      if(!empty(\filter_input(INPUT_POST,'submit')))
         {
           $sql="delete from cart where itemId='$itemId1'";
           $res=mysqli_query($dbhandle,$sql) or die(\mysqli_error($dbhandle));
         }
          echo"deleted successfully";
          $mysqli_close = \mysqli_close($dbhandle);
```

> i have retrieved  the value from cart table and displayed in the html table,each row havhaving a button to delete.But whenever i try to delete irrespective of the button,only the first row of the table gets deleted.I guess the sql query in the deletecart.php is wrong.Please correct the code and the query..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not in the cart delete, it is in order.php. Two things I see here.

First up, you are opening each form inside the while loop but you don't close the form until outside the loop (and you never closed the <tr>s). This results in:

```
<form id="addform" method="post" action="cartdelete.php">
....
<form id="addform" method="post" action="cartdelete.php">
....
<form id="addform" method="post" action="cartdelete.php">
....
</form>
```

Only the **outer form** is closed. That corresponds to the first row on the table. No matter which submit button you click in the table, they all map back to the first one.

Second, I suggest you give each form a unique id.

```
echo "<form id=\"addform" . echo $row['itemId'] . "\" method="post" action="cartdelete.php"> ';
```

I have had instances of multiple forms on a page with the same id giving different results in different browsers.

```
$total = 0;
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)) 
{
    $amount=$row['price']*$row['quantity'];
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" .$row['subtitle'] ."</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$row['quantity'] ."</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$row['price'] ."</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $amount . "</td>";
    echo "<form id='addform{$row['itemId']}' method='post' action='cartdelete.php'> ";
    echo "<td><input type='submit' value='x' name='submit'></td>";

    echo "<td><input type='text' name='itemId'  value= '{$row['itemId']}'></td>";     
    echo"</form>";
    echo "</tr>";
    $total += $amount;
}
echo "</table>";
```

There is also a problem in the cartdelete.php. This line:

```
$sql1="select itemId from cart";
```

will only find the very first item in the cart. No matter what, it will never find the second or third item. It might not even be needed. Since I don't know the table structure, try this:

```
  $itemId=(filter_input(\INPUT_POST,'itemId'));
  if(!empty(\filter_input(INPUT_POST,'submit')))
     {
       $sql="delete from cart where itemId='$itemId'";
       $res=mysqli_query($dbhandle,$sql) or die(\mysqli_error($dbhandle));
     }
      echo"deleted successfully";
      $mysqli_close = \mysqli_close($dbhandle);
```

Comment: method="post" action="cartdelete.php">
Subtitle Quantity Price Amount
Cornetto 1 80.0000 80  
Magnum175.000075
" method="post" action="cartdelete.php"> this is only the output im getting for the above code

Comment: the only one value is displayed inside the table,im using chrome browser

Comment: may i know why have u closed the table twice

Comment: @user3516005, closing the table twice was a mistake, and there were a few errors in the code that should be taken care of now.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'itemId' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' this is what the error i get when i echo the form

Comment: Try again. I think you copied while I was fixing.

Comment: even now only the first row gets deleted

Comment: can u please check my cartdelete.php file,so that the problem is not caused coz of that file

Comment: @user3516005, yes there was an error in that file. I have edited the fix into my answer.

Comment: i have sorted out along with your help in order.php file.Now the error is in the cartdelete.php file in the select statement there is no where clause.I have given that and hence the problem solved.Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user3516005, If this has helped you, please upvote and accept it. Thank you.

Comment: i have one doubt if v dont put the buttons inside the <td> is that not possible to achieve this delete?

Comment: because i don't need it to be displayed it in another column,is that possible?

Comment: It has to be in some TD to render in the right place, but it could be in the same TD as another element. As long as the delete button and itemId are inside the form, it will work. You might try putting the whole TR inside the form.

Answer (score 1):

Depends, if you're trying to delete one row then this is fine:

```
$sql="delete from cart where itemId='$itemId1'";
```

However to delete all it's simply:

$sql="DELETE * from cart";

Comment: with this only the first row gets deleted from table,$sql="DELETE * from cart";deletes all records,but i need only the corresponding product of the button to be deleted